# Equal return False. What's wrong with this code?

Tags: java

I have java syntax. Sory I'm still not figure out why this happen.

```
public class TestString {
  public static void main(String [] args){
    int i=-1;
    String a=((Object)i).toString();
    if(a=="-1"){
        System.out.println("Same");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Not");
    }
  }
}
```

And then the result is "Not" what the problems why -1 string different with -1 int in object?

Comment: try to print a and see the difference ;)

Comment: Use .equals() to compare the string

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `.equals()` on string to compare.

[String's equal method overridden in such a way.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

Try

```
public class TestString {
  public static void main(String [] args){
    int i=-1;
    String a=((Object)i).toString();
    if(a.equals("-1")){
        System.out.println("Same");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Not");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings have to be compared with the .equals() method.

Comment: Thanks sory I come from C# behavior.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using *reference equality* instead of *object equality*.

Since `"-1"` in the literal table has a different heap address than a newly allocated `a`, it returns `false`.

If for some reason you find yourself allocating a lot of `String` objects that share the same value(s) and want to test them by reference instead, consider using `String#intern()`:

```
final String a = [...].intern(); // allocated
if (a == SOME_INTERNED_STRING_1) {
  [...]
else if (a == SOME_INTERNED_STRING_2) {
  [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ==

compares reference which is not same in your case so if you want to compare string values then use

> .equals() method

Answer (score 0):

The == operator checks to see if two objects are exactly the same object . You can go for equals method to check if the value are equal or not

Comment: The objects are not even accessed when using `==` (reference equals) operator. The only thing being tested is their heap addresses.